# Alamofire retry request - reactive way

Tags: swift, alamofire, rx-swift, reactivex

I was looking at those two:

- http://sapandiwakar.in/refresh-oauth-tokens-using-moya-rxswift/
- [Using retryWhen to update tokens based on http error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281760/using-retrywhen-to-update-tokens-based-on-http-error-code)

And trying to create *similiar* thing, but without Moya, using Alamofire + RxSwift.

First of all is obviously where should I stick this, since my implementation is divided into a couple smaller parts.
First of all I have my custom method for generating **reactive** requests:

```
static func rx_request<T>(requestConvertible: URLRequestConvertible, completion: (Request) -> Observable<T> ) -> Observable<T> {
    let manager: Manager = Manager.sharedInstance
    return manager
        .rx_request { manager -> Request in
            return Alamofire.request(requestConvertible)
        }
        .flatMap { request -> Observable<T> in
            return completion(request)
        }
        .shareReplay(1)
}
```

Which is later used by specific `Request`s convenience classes. For example my `UserRequests` has this private extension to extract some common code from it's methods:

```
private extension Request {

    func rx_userRequest() -> Observable<User> {
        return self
            .validate()
            .rx_responseJSON()
            .flatMap{ (request, json) -> Observable<User> in
                guard
                    let dict = json as? [ String: AnyObject ],
                    let parsedUser: User = try? Unbox(dict) else {
                        return Observable.error(RequestError.ParsingError)
                }

                return Observable.just(parsedUser)
            }
            .rx_storeCredentials()
    }

}
```

Because of how things looks like I wonder whare's the *right* place to put a `retry` method and also how to implement it? Because depending on the location I can get different input arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The retry code has to go after the first try, which is `rx_responseJSON` so the way you have things setup now, it must go between that and the `flatMap` after it.